# Success And Error Messages Optimization In Nodejs application

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am working on a nodejs project and I am thinking of controlling all the success and error messages of the application from a single file or db. The messages is localized. Please suggest me the best approach or libraries of doing this. Thanks.

Comment: I would recommend asking a more specific question. This question may get downvoted as too broad and open to opinion.

Comment: maybe this project might help, https://github.com/Atishay96/boiler_plate/blob/master/helper/Response.js

Comment: Thank Atishay for your comment but i am looking to put all the "messages strings" in a single file so if i want to change some message later in the development i don't have to look in the controllers.